# Keyword Search using AND criteria embedded in INDEX

Tags: arrays, excel, if-statement, search, indexing

I have 3 keywords to look for in an array. They must all be present in a cell and recognized in any order. EXAMPLE: I'm looking for A, B, and C. The cell might contain "A,B,C", "A,C,B", "C,B,A", etc. It needs to find them all.

Here's what I've got that successfully pulls the array for the first keyword.
Assume my first keyword is in A2. Second and third would go in A3 and A4, respectively.

Data set being searched lives in the "Lock_Full Data" sheet. The search results are populated on their own sheet, "Search Results".

I absolutely can't figure out how to look for multiple values!

```
=IF($A$2="","",
   IF(ISERROR(INDEX('Lock_Full Data'!$A:$D,
   SMALL(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($A$2,'Lock_Full Data'!$D:$D)),
   ROW('Lock_Full Data'!$D:$D)),ROW(7:7)),1)),"",
   INDEX('Lock_Full Data'!$A:$D,
   SMALL(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($A$2,'Lock_Full Data'!$D:$D)),
   ROW('Lock_Full Data'!$D:$D)),ROW(7:7)),1)))
```

Comment: For clarification, which sheet is this formula in? Do you always have 3 and only 3 keywords? What are you putting in sheet 'search results'? Can you show an example of your data in Lock_Full Data.

Comment: The formulas (array) is in a sheet called "Search Results". It would never be more than three, but a single keyword or two keywords are a possibility.

Comment: I'm working on a mock up of the data. I can't post what I'm actually working on, too much sensitive data.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use a restricted range rather than using full columns, so assuming data in rows 2 to 100 (change as required) you can use this formula

`=IF(COUNTA(A$2:A$4)<3,"",IFERROR(INDEX('Lock_Full Data'!A$2:A$100,AGGREGATE(15,6,(ROW('Lock_Full Data'!D$2:D$100)-ROW('Lock_Full Data'!D$2)+1)/(MMULT(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(TRANSPOSE(A$2:A$4),'Lock_Full Data'!D$2:D$100))+0,{1;1;1})=3),ROWS(F$7:F7))),""))`

confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> and copied down

An alternative version uses `SMALL` function like this:

`=IF(COUNTA(A$2:A$4)<3,"",IFERROR(INDEX('Lock_Full Data'!A$2:A$100,SMALL(IF(MMULT(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(TRANSPOSE(A$2:A$4),'Lock_Full Data'!D$2:D$100))+0,{1;1;1})=3,ROW('Lock_Full Data'!D$2:D$100)-ROW('Lock_Full Data'!D$2)+1),ROWS(F$7:F7))),""))`

Assumes first formula in cell `F7` - if different then change the `ROWS(F$7:F7)` part in formula to match. Note - if you make `A2:A4` into a horizontal range like `A2:C2` then you can get rid of `TRANSPOSE` function

You can easily expand this version to cater for 5 or 10 or more search terms, just change the 3s and the `{1;1;1}` as appropriate

Comment: Could you explain the use of AGGREGATE (15,6...)? I'm not very familiar with that function and I don't understand why 15 and 6.

Comment: AGGREGATE can perform multiple functions, 15 denotes SMALL and 6 tells the function to ignore errors. You could use SMALL almost as easily here, if you want I can update my answer with a version that uses SMALL function

Comment: I likely won't use SMALL because your explanation makes sense, but in the interest of learning, if you have a moment, I would like to see its proper use.

Comment: I edited my answer to show both. In this case SMALL might be better. `AGGREGATE` itself doesn't require "array entry" but in this case the use of `TRANSPOSE` forces it

Comment: Thank you! This will be a great jumping off point for me to dive into really understanding how some of these more complicated formulas truly work!

Comment: How would I edit this to be an OR type statement rather than including all three of the criteria. Instead of meeting all three at once, I now need it to display any row that has any of the keywords in A2:A4.

Comment: @moosebiz - where the formula says `=3`, that means all 3 have to be found. If you change that to `>0` then that will give you any rows that have 1 or more match